# Removing directories from PATH

Tags: bash, path, environment-variables

I am trying to run `rkhunter`, but it is giving me this output:

```
stack/security/rkhunter-1.4.6
➜ sudo rkhunter --check
Password:
Invalid BINDIR configuration option: Invalid directory found: ~/.dotnet/tools
Invalid BINDIR configuration option: Invalid directory found: 
Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
```

How do I go into my PATH variable and remove these directories from all shell sessions? None of these directories are in my .bash_profile or .bashrc.

Comment: Check if you have a .profile or .bash_login file in your home directory.

Comment: You are most likely not getting those errors due to presence of the mentioned directories in your $PATH. Rather it's the error thrown by the command due to missing configuration files. Try reinstalling `rkhunter` by running `brew reinstall rkhunter`.

Comment: @NimeshNeema yes I had a .bash_profile. Do you want to see its contents? I reinstalled rkhunter with that command, but it still doesn't work when I run the check.

Comment: It's most likely an error due to invalid configuration. Please edit the question to include the complete command line that you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of /etc/paths or /etc/paths.d/

Comment: /etc/paths.d
➜ ls
10-BitKeeper             com.vmware.fusion.public go
40-XQuartz               dotnet                   mono-commands
Wireshark                dotnet-cli-tools         workbooks

Comment: What about ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_rc ?

Comment: export PATH="/Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:$PATH"
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"

Comment: This is ~/.bash_rc. ~/.bash_profile is too long to post in comments.